# Python OpenCV: Getting a x/y point with a slope and another coordinate

Tags: python, numpy, video, opencv

I am trying to draw a straight line representing the path of a linear moving object. I work out the slope by getting the first point `(oX,oY)` and the second point `(x3, y3)` and doing `((y3-oY)/(x3-oX))`. I now have a point `(x3, y3)` and the slope. Depending on where the line is going e.g if it intersects the left, right, up or down border gives me another point based on the height and length of the window (640px, 480px). So if the line intersects the left side, the x value is 0 and all I would need to do is find the y value. How can I do this with all 4 sides? My code is below and currently draws the line fine but does not stop at the top or bottom. e.g the y value is not either 0 or 480. The reason I would need the line to stop at the edge of the window is to then draw an identical line with an inverted slope to represent if the linear object were to bounce. Thank you!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

lower_red = np.array([-10,160,160])
upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])

oX, oY = 0,0

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    #ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(mask, 80, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    if len(contours) != 0:
        c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
        x1, y1, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        x2, y2 = x1 + w, y1 + h
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        x3, y3 = round((x1+x2)/2), round((y1+y2)/2)
        cv2.circle(frame, (x3,y3), 4, (255,0,0), 2)
        #print(x3, y3)

        def slope(oX,oY,x3,y3):
        ###finding slope
            if x3!=oX:
                return((y3-oY)/(x3-oX))
            else:
                return 'NA'

        slope(oX,oY,x3,y3)

    def drawLine(frame,oX,oY,x3,y3):
        m=slope(oX,oY,x3,y3)
        h,w=frame.shape[:2]
        if m!='NA':
            ### here we are essentially extending the line to x=0 and x=width
            ### and calculating the y associated with it
            ##starting point
            px=0
            py=-(oX-0)*m+oY
            ##ending point
            qx=w
            qy=-(x3-w)*m+y3
        else:
        ### if slope is zero, draw a line with x=x1 and y=0 and y=height
            px,py=oX,0
            qx,qy=oX,h

        if x3 < oX and y3 < oY:
            qx, qy = oX, oY
            cv2.line(frame, (int(px), int(py)), (int(qx), int(qy)), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        elif x3 < oX and y3 > oY:
            qx, qy = oX, oY
            cv2.line(frame, (int(px), int(py)), (int(qx), int(qy)), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        elif x3 > oX and y3 < oY:
            px, py = oX, oY
            cv2.line(frame, (int(px), int(py)), (int(qx), int(qy)), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        elif x3 > oX and y3 > oY:
            px, py = oX, oY
            cv2.line(frame, (int(px), int(py)),(int(qx), int(qy)), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        #print(int(px),int(py), int(qx), int(qy))


    drawLine(frame,oX,oY,x3,y3)
    oX, oY = x3, y3
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know cv2 but the code below will return the end points on the outline of a box of a line that crosses it.  It's pure python no numpy so works on one box/line at a time.  If the line doesn't intersect the box a zero length list is returned.

```
from math import isclose

def grad_and_inter( x0, y0, x1, y1 ):
    """ Return gradient and intercept in y = gradient * x + intercept
        for a line through (x0,y0) and (x1, y1) """
    try:
        grad = (y1-y0) / (x1-x0)
        return grad, y0 - grad * x0  # gradient & intercept
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return float('Inf'), x0      # if vertical Inf and x

def frame_intersect( xlo, ylo, xhi, yhi, grad, inter ):
    """ Return the 2 points on the bounding box (xlo, ylo), (xhi, yhi)
        where a line (y = grad * x + inter) intercepts the box. """

    if grad == 0.0:    # y = inter for all x 
        return [ (xlo, inter), (xhi, inter) ]

    if grad == float('Inf'):  # x = inter for all y
        return [(inter, ylo), (inter, yhi) ]

    def y_func( x ):
        y = grad * x + inter
        if (y < ylo) or (y > yhi):
            return None   # Return None if outside the bounds
        return ( x, y )  # Return x and the calculated y

    def x_func( y ):
        x = (y - inter) / grad
        if (x < xlo) or (x>xhi):
            return None   # Return None if outside the bounds
        return ( x, y )  # Return calculated x and y

    func = [ x_func, x_func, y_func, y_func ] # Iterate through the 4 funcs
    param = [ ylo, yhi, xlo, xhi ]            # with the 4 parameters.

    res = []
    first_x = float('Inf')  # first_x must be a float for isclose below.
    for f, p in zip(func, param):
        coords  = f(p)
        if coords is None:
            continue
        if not isclose(first_x, coords[0]):  
            # If the x in coord is the same as the first x don't append it.
            # If one (or both) coords are a corner they'll be repeated.
            res.append(coords)
            if len(res)>1:
                break  # Once two coords found break.
            first_x = coords[0]

    return res

def constant_frame( xlo, ylo, xhi, yhi ):
    """ Returns a function that uses a constant bounding box. """

    def user_func( x0, y0, x1, y1 ):
        return frame_intersect( xlo, ylo, xhi, yhi, *grad_and_inter( x0, y0, x1, y1 ) )

    return user_func

do_640x480 = constant_frame( 0., 0., 640., 480. )

print( 247., 50., 247., 10., do_640x480( 247., 50., 247., 10. ) ) # Vertical
print( 123., 50., 456., 50. , do_640x480( 123., 50., 456., 50. ) ) # Horizontal
print( 10., 50., 450, 450., do_640x480( 10., 50., 450, 450.) )
print( 10., 5., 630, 300., do_640x480( 10., 5., 630, 300.) )
print( 10., 300., 530, 5., do_640x480( 10., 300., 530, 5.) )
print( 10., 5., 500, 400., do_640x480( 10., 5., 500, 400.) )
print( 10., 10.,500, 300., do_640x480( 10., 10., 500, 300.) )


# 247.0 50.0 247.0 10.0 [(247.0, 0.0), (247.0, 480.0)]
#  50.0 456.0 50.0 [(0.0, 50.0), (640.0, 50.0)]
#  50.0 450 450.0 [(483.00000000000006, 480.0), (0.0, 40.90909090909091)]
#  5.0 630 300.0 [(0.0, 0.24193548387096797), (640.0, 304.758064516129)]
#  300.0 530 5.0 [(538.8135593220339, 0.0), (0.0, 305.6730769230769)]
#  5.0 500 400.0 [(3.79746835443038, 0.0), (599.2405063291139, 480.0)]
#  10.0 500 300.0 [(0.0, 4.081632653061225), (640.0, 382.85714285714283)
```

This may not be what you need but hopefully points in the right direction.

Comment: this is sort of on the right track. Thank you for your help it has cleared some things up but I still need to work the solution out.